# Output PGSQL commands from inside of an anonymous block to a SQL file

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I have tried to output some `pgsql` commands - specifically grants - to an SQL file.

My code looks like this:

```
DO
$$

DECLARE
rec record;

BEGIN

FOR rec in
SELECT 
    pu.usename,
    pr.rolname,
    tp.privilege_type,
    tp.table_name
FROM 
    pg_user pu
JOIN 
    pg_auth_members ON pu.usesysid = pg_auth_members.member
JOIN 
    pg_roles pr ON pr.oid = pg_auth_members.roleid
LEFT JOIN 
    information_schema.table_privileges tp ON pr.rolname = tp.grantee
  
  LOOP
    
    CONTINUE WHEN rec.table_name is null;
    execute 'copy (''grant ' ||rec.privilege_type|| ' on ' ||rec.table_name|| ' to ' ||rec.usename|| ';'') to
    /mydir/backup.csv with csv';

  END LOOP;
    
END
$$;
```

In my code, I am rather trying to output the code into a CSV file, because I don't know how to do it with an SQL file, and anyway if it is not possible, I can reuse the CSV file.

I am getting an error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'grant SELECT on t_table to user2;'"
LINE 1: copy ('grant SELECT on t_table to user2;') to
              ^
QUERY:  copy ('grant SELECT on t_table to user2;') to
    /mydir/backup.csv with csv
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 27 at EXECUTE
```

I unfortunately don't know what syntax error I am making and I don't know if I will achieve the goal to output the grants to the CSV or SQL file after having corrected the syntax error.

Could anyone tell me what is the syntax error? And will this execute command really create a CSV file with my grants? Should I create an empty file before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COPY` does not write a string to a file, it writes the contents of a table (or the *result* of an SQL statement) to a file.

What you could do is collect your `GRANT` statements in a temporary table and `COPY` that to a file in the end:

```
BEGIN
   ...

   CREATE TEMP TABLE tt (x text);

   LOOP
      ...
      INSERT INTO tt VALUES (
         /* prevent SQL injection */
         format(
            'GRANT %s ON %I to %I;',
            rec.privilege_type, rec.table_name, rec.usename
         )
      );
   END LOOP;

   ...
   COPY tt TO '/mydir/backup.csv';
END;
```

But in your special case, you don't need a loop at all. You can write a query that returns a table of `GRANT` statements and use it like

```
COPY (SELECT ...) TO '/mydir/backup.csv';
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it (output strings like "create user...", "grant usage on schema...", etc. into an sql file) without the superuser privilege? I saw something about security definer, but I cannot do that either.

Comment: You don't need a superuser. You can either use a user that is a member of `pg_write_server_files`, or you can create a `SECURITY DEFINER` function owned by such a user.

Comment: I unfortunately cannot see any user who is member of pg_write_server_files.

I am trying to copy the content from the temporary table to a file like this:

for rec in
SELECT * FROM TT
loop
  execute '\copy ' ||rec|| ' to ''\mydir\backup.sql'';';
end loop;

but it is executing the commands and I am getting an error that a user already exists...

Comment: You probably have to `GRANT` the role to a user.